# How to pass data from one table view to another table view in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView: UITableView
    var dict1:Dictionary<Int,String> = [ 0:"One",1:"TwO",2:"Three"];

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dict1.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = self.dict1[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

    }               
}
```

Comment: You need to pass selectedIndex values to other ViewController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly build the new view controller and pass the data in when you detect that a row is selected:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath path: NSIndexPath!) {
    let entry = news[path.row] as NSDictionary
    let url = entry["link"] as NSString
    let secondViewController = 
        self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController")
        as SecondViewController

    // pass the relevant data to the new sub-ViewController
    secondViewController.url=url;
    // tell the new controller to present itself
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

and in SecondViewController.swift, add a variable to hold the relevant data.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var url: String? = ""
}
```